# Persisting search criterias in the database using Entity Framework

Tags: mysql, entity-framework

I have a number of search criterias which have different attributes and values.
I  wish to save the search criteria in the database so that the users dont have to re-enter the search criteria again and again . Also, these search criterias can be shared with other users.

I am unable to figure out a way by which the search criteria can be persisted in the database using Entity Framework.

How do I save the search criterias in the MySql database? What are the design considerations to be looked into ? What will be my database schema like ?

Kindly provide me your ideas / suggestions.

Comment: Nobody is going to do the work for you. You need to make at least a rudimentary attempt at it.

Comment: Shoe...I dont expect anybody doing work for me. However, I am looking out for the design considerations to be looked into so that I can design the database schema.